# jQuery - How to select the first parent of an element and add a new class "testclass"

Tags: jquery

First Name

Given element 'element_1', how to select its first parent with tag name as li?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#element_1').closest('li').addClass('testclass');
```

assuming you're using `jQuery 1.3+` and `element_1` is an `ID`.

`jQuery` < 1.3 should look like

```
$('#element_1').parents('li').addClass('testclass');
```

Reference: [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure closest() was in 1.3+

Comment: jAndy - You probably should have the `:first` selector for the `.parents()` version in case of nested lists.

Comment: @patrick: that would mean multiple unique ID's in the markup right?

Comment: @jAndy - No, I mean for the `li`, as in `.parents('li:first')`. If there are nested lists, using `.parents()` will add the class to *all* the ancestor `<li>` elements. That way it more accurately emulates `.closest()`.

Comment: Hello patrick,
your solution is the one that i am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

`$('#element_1').closest('li').addClass('testclass');`

Comment: Thank you very much tvanfosson!